list index out of range with a while loop explanation
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
i = 0
while i < len(A) :
    i += 1
    print(A[i])

and the output gave me
2
3
4
5
which is understandable but I don't see how my index is out of range , someone please help me
I only expect the result without the "1" but I don't know why it also has index error out of range , I know I can fix this by replace the order of my 4th and 5th line but I'm curious why my original answer have such error

On the last loop iteration i starts as 4, then you add 1 to it so it is now 5, then you try to access A[5] which is out of bounds.  Can you say why you expected otherwise?

... and 4 is less than len(A) so the loop continues and then as JG states the value of 'i' is immediately incremented to 5 etc etc

print(A[i]); i += 1 will work. Elements of the list A are A[0] to A[len(A)-1]

Even though SO might not be the best place for this question, I think it is a really good example of how to develop debugging skills. If you practice trying to step through what this code is doing in your head on each iteration the answer will eventually jump out at you.

The loop condition while i < len(A) guarantees that at the start of the loop, you always have i < len(A) (otherwise you would have exited the loop).
But, at the first line of the loop, you add 1 to i. So now i may be equal to len(A)…
This is exactly whats happens at the last (4th) iteration of your loop: at the start, i=4 which does verify the condition i < len(A) since len(A) is 5. But then you add 1 to i. So i = 5, which is out of bounds (remember: the list indices start at 0, so valid indices are 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4. )

When you perform this:
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
i = 0
while i < len(A):
    i += 1
    print(A[i]) # A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4], A[5]

A[5] will be out of bound since index start from zero.
This might be what you expect:
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
i = 0
while i < len(A):
    print(A[i]) # A[0], A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4]
    i += 1 # At the end of loop, i is equal to 5 and then exit the while loop.

Here, A[4] is defined, which is 5.
